# Mount ext4 formatted mircosd on Nvidia Shield TV

Tags: ext4, android, automounting

I have a rooted Shield TV but I can't figure out how to mount the microsd card. 
I see that the file system is supported but I don't see where the device is listed.
Usually I would look for mmcblk or something.

shell@foster:/ $ cat /proc/filesystems 
ext3
ext2
ext4